# Storing log-in details for Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, authentication, xamarin

I am getting started with Xamarin iOS and writing an app that requires the user to log in, using their phone number (which can hopefully be pulled from the phone via API). What I would like is the first time they use the app, to see log in and sign up buttons. Sign up takes them through a storyboard to enter information which ends up saving their details in my server database so their account is now open. Log in will check if their phone number is registered and if so, sign them in to the app based on their phone number.

However if the app closes or the phone restarts, I would like them to be automatically logged in the next time they open the app, if they have previously created an account.

I am reading a lot of tutorials on sign up/login screens but none talk about how to have an "automatic" log-in option once they have authenticated, at least until they manually click the log out button. Lots of apps do this so Im sure it should be trivial, can anyone point me in the right direction? Do I have to store a value in the iOS file system or preferences folder structure? Maintain a local iOS DB with these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS has a [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSUserDefaults/) class that let's you store small bits of user configuration data in a persistent manner.

You can also use the iOS [Keychain](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/Keychain) to securely store user credentials.